# How to download a file with the ghost.py module?

Tags: python, ghost.py

For this example, I know it is easier to use requests or similar python module.
But I need to do it with the ghost.py module

This code sample doesn't work:

```
from ghost import Ghost

ghost = Ghost()

with ghost.start() as session:
    page, extra_resources = session.open('http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1506-x64.exe')

    with open('7z1506-x64.exe', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(session.http_resources)
```

Comment: Nobody? Is it possible? I don't find any download method in the module.

Answer (score 0):

I create some snippet here:
https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/issues/273

But it's not final solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Ghost.py (0.2.3)

```
    ...
    with open('7z1506-x64.exe', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(eval(extra_resources[0].content))
```